# How to write a Heterogeneous list on HList?

Tags: haskell

I want to use [HList: Heterogeneous lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList).

Installed the library then `import Data.HList (HList)` has been done so far.

Now investigating https://bitbucket.org/HList/hlist/src/master/examples/HListExample/ does not help me to start writing the code.

What I want to do is,

1. create a hello-world Heterogeneous lists such as `H[1, "2"]` (not sure about the syntax at all)
2. map the Heterogeneous lists to `print` each.

Is there anyone familiar to how to use `HList`?

Comment: You work with `HCons 1 (HCons "2" HNil)`.

Comment: "Example"? At a glance, those look more like unit tests than tutorial documents. I don't fault you in the slightest for being confused by that.

Comment: Oh is that the only syntax to build a list? I mean no shorthand such as `H([1, "2"])` ??

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I thought so, too, but unfortunately I could not find any other tutorial document. Very hard to scratch.

Comment: @Functor: that would be impossible, since at that time, the `[1, "2"]` is already a (vanilla) list, and that list thus requires the elements to be all of the same type. One could use quasiquoters or perhaps template Haskell, but not a simple list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That makes sense. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to just *map* over the HList, but to *traverse* over it, aka [`mapM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM). And you're probably not interested in the individial result-`()`s but only the side effects, so that would be [`mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) then.

HList does have a general tool for that, called unsurprisingly [`hMapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-HList.html#v:hMapM_). Using it with arbitrary constrained-polymorphic functions is a bit involved, but for printing specifically this is actually shipped ready-for-use with the library:

```
Prelude Data.HList> let l = 1.*."2".*.HNil :: HList '[Int, String]
Prelude Data.HList> l
H[1,"2"]
Prelude Data.HList> hMapM_ HPrint l
1
"2"
```

As Noughtmare commented, the way to use this with other polymorphic functions (without having to write a custom type) is to use [`Fun`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-HList.html#t:Fun), like

```
Prelude Data.HList> hMapM_ (Fun print :: Fun Show (IO ())) l
1
"2"
```

...which is not *too* awkward, but still a bit annoying. I'd define a synonym that allows writing this with TypeApplications to avoid redundancy:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, RankNTypes, ConstraintKinds, UnicodeSyntax #-}

import Data.Kind

fun :: ∀ (cxt :: Type -> Constraint) getb
        . (∀ a. (cxt a) => a -> getb) -> Fun cxt getb
fun = Fun
```

and then

```
Prelude Data.HList Data.Kind> :set -XTypeApplications
Prelude Data.HList Data.Kind> hMapM_ (fun @Show print) l
1
"2"
```

Or we could even make it

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

h'MapM_ :: ∀ (cxt :: Type -> Constraint) l m
   . (Monad m, HFoldr (Mapcar (Fun cxt (m ()))) [m ()] l [m ()])
    => (∀ a. (cxt a) => a -> m ()) -> HList l -> m ()
h'MapM_ f = hMapM_ (Fun f :: Fun cxt (m ()))
```

and then

```
Prelude Data.HList Data.Kind> h'MapM_ @Show print l
1
"2"
```

Comment: Thanks as always. Actually, I was investigating the API about map. Now I can start to use.

Comment: The documentation also points out the more general form: `hMapM_ (Fun print :: Fun Show (IO ())) l`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra edit. Now I started the related question on top of this. Please review thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71332269/17053359

Answer (score 5):

You can construct an HList by using the `hEnd` and `hBuild` functions, e.g.:

```
hello = hEnd (hBuild 1 "2")
```

Mapping `print` over this list is much more difficult. I think there is no easy way to write a higher order function that is able to map `print` over the HList, but you can manually traverse the HList like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

import Data.HList

class PrintEach ts where
  printEach :: HList ts -> IO ()
instance PrintEach '[] where
  printEach HNil = pure ()
instance (Show t, PrintEach ts) => PrintEach (t : ts) where
  printEach (HCons x xs) = print x *> printEach xs

hello = hEnd (hBuild 1 "2")

main = printEach hello
-- This prints:
-- 1
-- "2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know the `hbuild` API and now I understand how to structure the lists. Actually, now I do ` hEnd $ hBuild 1 "2"` .

Comment: Since using constraint kind things are hard even using map API of HList, I study your code again.

Comment: I have a related question on top of this. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349025/traversing-hlist-heterogeneous-list-manually-in-haskell