# Heterogeneous list / HList l -> [e]?

Tags: haskell

Thanks for the answers of my other quesion -
[How to write a Heterogeneous list on HList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71304552/how-to-write-a-heterogeneous-list-on-hlist) , I could start using [HList: Heterogeneous lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList), mostly with API of  https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-HList-HList.html

Now, I want - [producing homogenous lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-HList-HList.html#g:25) as `HList l -> [e]`

`hMapOut :: forall f e l. HMapOut f l e => f -> HList l -> [e]`

I've been trying create my own proof of concept code, but don't know how to do it properly.

```
import Data.HList (HList, hBuild, hEnd, hMap, hMapOut)

iA :: [Int]
iA = [1, 2, 3] :: [Int]

iB :: [[Char]]
iB = ["foo", "bar"] :: [[Char]]

iAiB :: HList '[[Int], [[Char]]]
iAiB = hEnd $ hBuild iA iB

flag :: Any -> Bool
flag = \iX ->  length iX >= 3  --- ERROR HERE

flags :: HList l -> [e]
flags = \iList ->
  iList & hMapOut flag

iBool :: [e]
iBool = flags iAiB

main :: IO ()
main = print iBool
```

This is the simplest example, and for my purpose, it needs to be wrapped into `IO`, in either way, it has the identical error.

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 a0’ with actual type ‘Any’
• In the first argument of ‘length’, namely ‘x’
  In the first argument of ‘(>=)’, namely ‘length x’
  In the expression: length x >= 3 typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)
```

I suppose `Any` type is wrong, but I don't know how to type. Advice?

---

I also did

```
flag :: forall (t :: * -> *) a. Foldable t => t a -> Bool
flag = \iX ->  length iX >= 3
```

This eliminates the error for this function, but now another error on

```
flags :: HList l -> [e]
flags = \iList ->
  iList & hMapOut flag --- ERROR HERE
```

as

```
• Ambiguous type variables ‘t0’,
                           ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘hMapOut’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Data.HList.HList.HFoldr
```

So, which seems to be the fundamental problem.

---

tried [Fun'](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-HList.html#t:Fun-39-)

```
import Data.HList (HList, hBuild, hEnd, hMap, hMapOut, Fun' (Fun'))

flags :: HList l -> [e]
flags = \iList ->
  iList & hMapOut (Fun' flag :: Fun' Foldable Bool)
```

error:

```
• Could not deduce: b ~ Bool
  from the context: Data.HList.FakePrelude.FunCxt Foldable b
    bound by a type expected by the context:
               forall b.
               Data.HList.FakePrelude.FunCxt Foldable b =>
               Data.HList.FakePrelude.FunApp Bool b -> b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second version, `flag :: ∀ t a. Foldable t => t a -> Bool`, is sensible. But mapping this over a HList is a bit tricky because the constraint doesn't have the form `Type -> Constraint`, instead it's the application of `t` with a `(Type -> Type) -> Constraint`.

Since you don't seem to require supporting generic foldable containers (and FWIW the `Foldable`-based definition of `length` is [a bit dubious anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36460833/why-does-length-return-1-for-a-tuple-with-2-elements-and-gives-an-error-for-a-t)) I'd suggest instead using the [`IsList` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:IsList):

```
flag :: ∀ l. IsList l => l -> Bool
flag = (>=3) . length . toList
```

Alternatively, we can quickly wrap `Foldable` into our own class with `Type -> Constraint` signature:

```
class HasLength l where gLength :: l -> Int
instance Foldable t => HasLength (t a) where gLength = length

flag :: ∀ l. HasLength l => l -> Bool
flag = (>=3) . gLength
```

Now this is easy enough to fold over a HList:

```
flags :: HMapOut (Fun IsList Bool) l Bool
           => HList l -> [Bool]
flags = hMapOut (Fun flag :: Fun IsList Bool)
```

Note that this is `Fun`, not `Fun'`. The latter doesn't work in this situation (and generally with `HMapOut`), because the function is polymorphic in its *input*, i.e. it can't be possible to determine the input type from the output one.

Again, I'm inclined to define a helper to make this sort of definition more convenient:

```
h'MapOut :: ∀ (cxt :: Type -> Constraint) getb l
           . HMapOut (Fun cxt getb) l getb
         => (∀ a . (cxt a) => a -> getb) -> HList l -> [getb]
h'MapOut f = hMapOut (Fun f :: Fun cxt getb)
```

and then simply

```
flags = h'MapOut @IsList flag
```

---

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax
        , KindSignatures, ConstraintKinds, RankNTypes
        , FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances
        , AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.HList
import GHC.Exts (IsList(..))
import Data.Kind

flag :: ∀ l. HasLength l => l -> Bool
flag = (>=3) . gLength
    
h'MapOut :: ∀ (cxt :: Type -> Constraint) getb l
           . HMapOut (Fun cxt getb) l getb
         => (∀ a . (cxt a) => a -> getb) -> HList l -> [getb]
h'MapOut f = hMapOut (Fun f :: Fun cxt getb)

flags :: HMapOut (Fun HasLength Bool) l Bool
           => HList l -> [Bool]
flags = h'MapOut @HasLength flag

class HasLength l where gLength :: l -> Int
instance Foldable t => HasLength (t a) where gLength = length
```

Comment: Thank you again! I don't know why but for some reason, my appreciation comment that existed here is deleted.

Comment: Maybe some automatic filter. StackOverflow comments aren't supposed to do stuff like thank or rate or redirect, they should only point out things that are wrong or unclear.

Comment: I see, but I really appreciated, and out of my curiosity, you use `∀` for `forall`. Do you use shortcut-key to type that? The reason you prefer to use the symbol is this is a key factor for type programming in Haskell and essential to you?

Comment: I like the compact appearance, same way I prefer Haskell's `\x` lambdas over the clunky `lambda x` style of some other languages. In Vim it's `ctrl+k` `F` `A`, in Emacs with LaTeX input mode it's `\forall`.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your idea again.

Comment: When I have `flag :: forall x. IO x -> IO Bool`, I need to define some "constraint" (new concept to me, that's why it's hard), `Foo` then modify it to `flag :: forall x. Foo x => IO x -> IO Bool`??

Comment: That looks a bit fishy, however you could write a class analogous to `HasLength` that should work there too.

Comment: Right, so considering the scenario, on second thought, probably I should do this manually. Please review my latest question. Thank you.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349025/traversing-hlist-heterogeneous-list-manually-in-haskell