# traversing HList - Heterogeneous list manually in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I try to use [HList: Heterogeneous lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList).

Based on my question: [How to write a Heterogeneous list on HList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71304552/how-to-write-a-heterogeneous-list-on-hlist)

Accoding to an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71306058/17053359

```
import Data.HList (HList (HCons, HNil), hBuild, hEnd)
```

On a HList of `hello`

```
hello :: HList '[Integer, [Char]]
hello = hEnd $ hBuild 1 "2"
```

I could traverse the list with `print`

```
class PrintEach ts where
  printEach :: HList ts -> IO ()

instance PrintEach '[] where
  printEach HNil = pure ()

instance (Show t, PrintEach ts) => PrintEach (t : ts) where
  printEach (HCons x xs) = print x *> printEach xs

main :: IO ()
main = printEach hello
-- 1 "2"
```

---

Now, I want to traverse/map `iAiB`

```
io :: a -> IO a
io = pure

iA :: IO Int
iA = io (1 :: Int)

iB :: IO [Char]
iB = io ("foo" :: [Char])

iAiB :: HList '[IO Int, IO [Char]]
iAiB = hEnd $ hBuild iA iB
```

to `[IO Bool]`

```
class MapToIObool ts where
  mapToIObool :: HList ts -> [IO Bool]

instance MapToIObool '[] where
  mapToIObool  HNil = []

instance ----------??
```

Here, for the simplicity, every element of `[IO Bool]` will be `io True` unconditionally.

```
result :: [IO Bool]
result = mapToIObool iAiB
-- expected result
result' :: [IO Bool]
result' = [io True, io True]
```

What is the code for `instance ----------??`

Comment: @Noughtmare Actually, I tried a lot on `HmapOut` & `Fnc` API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71332269/heterogeneous-list-hlist-l-e ,however, depending on the APIs makes the problem complicated, so I decided to go manually.

Comment: @Noughtmare I know what you mean, and I'm not just asking other person to write code..I thought I have proven what I've tried so far. I'm working on this for more than a week. The reason I ask in this from in this question is, in fact, I have no idea how the mechanism works. Honestly no idea.

Comment: discarding the return value by IO and constructing list is very different here, ans since I'm relatively new to Haskell, I'm learning by what I need to code. here is the one and probably reading the answer code here, I can understand the mechanism.

Comment: For instance `instance (Show t, PrintEach ts) => PrintEach (t : ts) where` this line, I understand a bit, but no idea how to apply this to `[IO bool]` because I think there's not such a thing corresponding to `Show` for `print`. However, if someone kindly offer the code, I will understand which is to which.

Comment: @Noughtmare I'm a beginner on this topic, but I've been a programmer for decades and published a book for JavaScript in Japan, and I'm not very comfortable with someone telling me how to learn programming. HList is what I need and I don't understand what's wrong with simply askking for the basic example. This is off-topic, and please avoid to reply me further. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's how you can do it:

```
instance MapToIObool ts => MapToIObool (t : ts) where
  mapToIObool (HCons x xs) = io True : mapToIObool xs
```